# What is the expected value of the product of two different functions applied over the same random variable?

Tags: integration, expected-value

I have the following question. Let's say I have a random variable $X$ with density $p(X)$, and two functions $f()$ and $g()$. I want to compute:

$$\int f(x)*g(x) p(x) dx$$

I cannot figure out what is the exact answer. My guess is that the following does not hold:

$$\int f(x)*g(x) p(x) dx \neq \int f(x) p(x) \int g(x) p(x) dx$$

Is there any exact answer for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $$\mathbb{E}[XY]=\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]=\int xp_X(x)dx\int x p_Y(x)dx.$$ In your case, excluding some trivial cases (for example, when $f$ or $g$ is a constant), $f(X)$ and $g(X)$ won't be independent, and the only possibility to compute $\mathbb{E}[f(X)g(Y)]$ will be using the definition: $$\int f(x) g(x)p(x)dx$$

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand.

Do you want to calculate

$$\mathbb{E}[f(x)g(x)]$$

??

the right formula is

$$\mathbb{E}[f(x)g(x)]=\int f(x)g(x) p(x)dx$$

Without further details you are done!